# How do I use react-albus with Reach Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, reach-router

In my Gatsby app, I want to use a `react-albus` wizard with Reach Router. Here's the example form `react-albus` documentation on how to use it with React Router, but I don't know how to modify that to work with Reach Router. Any help would be appreciated.

> Internally, React Albus uses history to maintain the ordering of steps. This makes integrating with React Router (or any other router) as easy as providing  with history and basename props.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Wizard } from 'react-albus';

const RoutedWizard = ({ children }) =>
  <Route
    render={({ history, match: { url } }) =>
      <Wizard history={history} basename={url}>
        {children}
      </Wizard>}
  />;

export default RoutedWizard;
```

Comment: You still have access to `react-router-dom` in Gatsby, since it's a React-based application. In fact, Gatsby `<Link>` it's an extension of `@reach/router` but you can choose not using it.

Comment: Well, I know, but I’d rather avoid using two similar libraries in the same app.

Comment: It looks like it's not possible.

https://github.com/americanexpress/react-albus/issues/99